# Convert list with multiple entries per day to standard daytime index and give each entry it's own column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Date       | col1 | col2 | col3
2010-01-01 | -1.4 | 0.0  | 0.0
2010-01-01 | -1.4 | 0.0  | 0.0
2010-01-01 | -2.4 | 0.0  | 0.66
2010-01-02 | -2.4 | 0.0  | 0.08
2010-01-02 | -4.3 | 0.0  | 0.1
2010-01-02 | -4.3 | 0.0  | 1.04
```

Same days refer to a specific city, so for 2010-01-01 there is data for 3 cities, same for 2010-01-02 and all other days (it's always the same amount, at the moment 13 cities = 13 rows per day).

The city names are in a list where the order of the cities is the same as the order of the days:

```
["city1", "city2", "city3"]
```

So "city1" is the first row for each day, then "city2", then "city3" and so on.

I need to get this format into a standard format where I can set the Date as the index, so need a format like this:

```
Date       | city1_col1 | city1_col2 | city1_col3 | city2_col1| city2_col2 | city2_col3 | city3_col1| city3_col2 | city3_col3
2010-01-01 | -1.4       | 0.0        | 0.0        | -1.4      | 0.0        | 0.0        | -2.4      | 0.0        | 0.66 
2010-01-02 | -2.4       |   0.0      | 0.08       | -4.3      | 0.0        | 0.1        | -4.3      | 0.0        | 1.04
```

The data is later merged with other dataframes where the indexes are also the days of the year so a multiindex won't work.

How can I achieve this with pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do that:

```
df["city"] = cities * (len(df) // len(cities))
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index="Date", columns="city")
df.columns = [c[1] + "_" + c[0] for c in df.columns]
df=df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

The output is:

```
            city1_col1  city1_col2  city1_col3  city2_col1  city2_col2  city2_col3  city3_col1  city3_col2  city3_col3
Date                                                                                                                  
2010-01-01        -1.4         0.0        0.00        -1.4         0.0         0.0        -2.4         0.0        0.66
2010-01-02        -2.4         0.0        0.08        -4.3         0.0         0.1        -4.3         0.0        1.04
```